# Limit of a summation, using integrals method: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1^{99} + 2^{99} + \cdots + n^{99}}{n^{100}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, limits, derivatives

I have seen an interesting question on stackexchange, which I would like to requote so that I can understand the answer =)

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1^{99} + 2^{99} + \cdots + n^{99}}{n^{100}}$

How can the numerator be expressed as an integral?

$= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1^{99} + 2^{99} + \cdots + n^{99}}{n^{100}}$

$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}  \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1\to n} k^{99} }{n^{100}}$

$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}  \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1\to n} k^{99} }{n^{100}}$

Any ideas?

Comment: use the squeeze theorem

Comment: The question mentioned in the body is most likely this one: [Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1^{99} + 2^{99} + \cdots + n^{99}}{n^{100}}$ using integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/948506)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then:

> $$
> \int_a^b f(x)~dx = \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f \left(a + k \left(\dfrac{b-a}{n}\right) \right)
> $$

Notice that:
$$
\dfrac{1^{99} + 2^{99} + \cdots + n^{99}}{n^{100}}
= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^{99}}{n^{100}}
= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{99}
= \frac{1 - 0}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(0 + k\left(\frac{1 - 0}{n}\right)\right)^{99}
$$
Hence, by taking $f(x) = x^{99}$ and $a = 0$ and $b = 1$, it follows that:
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1^{99} + 2^{99} + \cdots + n^{99}}{n^{100}}
= \int_0^1 x^{99} \, dx
= \left[ \frac{x^{100}}{100} \right]_0^1
= \frac{1}{100}
$$