# Proper definite of riemann integral (limit version)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, riemannian-geometry

I am sort of confused.

Suppose we are given the series,

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^{99}}{n^{100}}$

How can this be written as an integral, and what would the variable be?

In this series given, which terms are the **constants?** Is it $n^{100}$??

Wouldn't the above be written as,

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^{99}} \cdot \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^{99}}{1}$

So in the integral, what will be the "respect-to-variable?" Would it be:

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^{99}} \int_{0}^{1} k^{99} \text{dk}$

$= \displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^{99}} \frac{1}{100}$

But that is wrong as shown here: [Limit of a summation, using integrals method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990718/limit-of-a-summation-using-integrals-method)

Bottonlinequestion: **I am confused about how you write an integral from a SUM. Like what is variable the integral is made with respect to?**

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^{99}}{n^{100}}=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\Bigl(\frac{k}{n}\Bigr)^{99}.
$$
This is a Riemann sum for the integral
$$
\int_0^1 x^{99}\,dx.
$$

Comment: How did the $(k/n)$ turn into an $x$ like in your integral?

Comment: Do you know what a Riemann sum is?

Comment: Hi! I do know what a Riemann sum, but the only issue I have is converting the sum into an integral. So how did you do it?

Comment: Go the other way around. Given the integral, write a Riemann sum on the appropriate partition.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try here: Using a right hand sum, with $\Delta(x) = \frac{1}{n}$, we must "approximate" the area under $x^{99}$ using $n$ subintervals from $[0, 1]$. Right, the $f(x_i) = \frac{k}{n}$, but how do you get from the sum to the integral?

Comment: Practice! You have to recognize from the form of the sum the right function to put under the integral sign.

Comment: Thanks! Also, how did you choose the limits of the integral? I know $\Delta(x) = \frac{b-a}{n}$, but $b - a = 1$ could fit infinitely many values, $(b, a) = (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2).... (n, n-1)$ ?

Comment: $k/n$ goes from $1/n\approx0$ to $n/n=1$.

Comment: Hi! The only issue is the approximately $0$ and not exactly $=0$ and because $n/n = 1$, that shows the height of the function in the last subinterval $=1$, which is only possible at $x = 1$ right?

Comment: I am sorry, I think that you should do some thinking by yourself.